# Can Guard read rspec CLI options from the ~/.rspec file?

Tags: rspec2, guard

I want to *avoid* having to set the CLI options for each of my guardfiles' rspec sections, like so:

```
guard 'rspec', :cli => "--color --drb --format documentation", :version => 2 do
```

I took out those `:cli` options entirely and restarted Guard but it did not load my custom options from `~/.rspec`. I do not have a .rspec dotfile in my project dir either.

Any ideas on how to link up Guard with that dotfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
rspec_dotfile = File.expand_path("~/.rspec")
cli_options = File.exists?(rspec_dotfile) ? File.read(rspec_dotfile).chomp : "--some --default-options"
guard 'rspec', :cli => cli_options, :version => 2 do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I just confirmed that guard-rspec parses options from `~/.rspec` and the project root, although there does appear to be some black magic involved with how it parses values between the two files and its own defaults.

Comment: follow up to my previous comment: I can't seem to get the `--format documentation` to apply when it is in my `~/.rspec`. Changing the color, tag, and fail-fast options do work though.

Comment: follow up to my previous comment: I think the two files are being merged and the doc setting must have a precedence order.